# How to hold the heading on the Boeing 777 autopilot?

Tags: autopilot, boeing-777

I have X-Plane 10 with Boeing 777 Worldliner Pro- Extended Pack, which is designed to model the real-world operation of the 777.

Why does the AP never go to the heading hold direction even if I press the hold button?

[image: snapshot of the game]

Answer (score 12):

- Pressing the **heading hold button will assume the current heading**.
- Pressing **heading select will follow the course as selected in the display**; this can be set by pressing the rotary encoder. It is also visible on the heading bug.

[image: autopilot]

The Boeing 777 primary flight display will display **`HDG SEL`** and **`HDG HLD`** for each selection respectively.

[image: pfd]

Answer (score 0):

"Heading Hold" is installed mostly for ATC purposes. Generally to insure horizontal separation between two aircraft.
The pilot will receive that kind of message : "XXXXX...maintain present heading".
It has not been designed to intercept the displayed heading.